# Plotting masked numpy array leads to incorrect colorbar

Tags: numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to create a custom color bar for a matplotlib [PolyCollection](http://matplotlib.org/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.PolyCollection).  Everything seems ok until I attempt to plot a [masked array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.generic.html#using-numpy-ma).  The color bar no longer shows the correct colors even though the plot does.  Is there a different procedure for plotting masked arrays?

I'm using matplotlib 1.4.0 and numpy 1.8.

Here's my plotting code:

```
import numpy
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import PolyCollection

vertices = numpy.load('vertices.npy')
array = numpy.load('array.npy')

# Take 2d slice out of 3D array
slice_ = array[:, :, 0:1].flatten(order='F')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

poly = PolyCollection(vertices, array=slice_, edgecolors='black', linewidth=.25)

cm = mpl.colors.ListedColormap([(1.0, 0.0, 0.0), (.2, .5, .2)])
poly.set_cmap(cm)

bounds = [.1, .4, .6]
norm = mpl.colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, cm.N)

fig.colorbar(poly, ax=ax, orientation='vertical', boundaries=bounds, norm=norm)
ax.add_collection(poly, autolim=True)
ax.autoscale_view()
plt.show()
```

Here's what the plot looks like:

[image: Plot without masked array]

However, when I plot a masked array with the following change **before** the slicing:

```
array = numpy.ma.array(array, mask=array > .5)
```

I get a color bar that now shows only a single color. Even though both colors are (correctly) still shown in the plot.

[image: Plot with masked array]

Is there some trick to keeping a colobar consistent when plotting a masked array?  I know I can use `cm.set_bad` to change the color of masked values, but that's not quite what I'm looking for.  I want the color bar to show up the same between these two plots since both colors and the color bar itself should remain unchanged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the BoundaryNorm to the PolyCollection, `poly`. Otherwise, `poly.norm` gets set to a `matplotlib.colors.Normalize` instance by default:

```
In [119]: poly.norm
Out[119]: <matplotlib.colors.Normalize at 0x7faac4dc8210>
```

I have not stepped through the source code sufficiently to explain exactly what is happening in the code you posted, but I speculate that the interaction of this `Normalize` instance and the `BoundaryNorm` make the range of values seen by the `fig.colorbar` different than what you expected.

In any case, if you pass `norm=norm` to `PolyCollection`, then the result looks correct:

```
import numpy
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.collections as mcoll
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors

numpy.random.seed(4)
N, M = 3, 3
vertices = numpy.random.random((N, M, 2))
array = numpy.random.random((1, N, 2))
# vertices = numpy.load('vertices.npy')
# array = numpy.load('array.npy')
array = numpy.ma.array(array, mask=array > .5)
# Take 2d slice out of 3D array
slice_ = array[:, :, 0:1].flatten(order='F')
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

bounds = [.1, .4, .6]
cm = mpl.colors.ListedColormap([(1.0, 0.0, 0.0), (.2, .5, .2)])
norm = mpl.colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, cm.N)

poly = mcoll.PolyCollection(
    vertices, 
    array=slice_, 
    edgecolors='black', linewidth=.25, norm=norm)

poly.set_cmap(cm)

fig.colorbar(poly, ax=ax, orientation='vertical')
ax.add_collection(poly, autolim=True)
ax.autoscale_view()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  You're right in that something about `fig.colorbar` doesn't pull the `BoundaryNorm` instance correctly.